# How to use --keepdb when run the command "python manage.py test"?

Tags: django

First seeing this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

I understand like this:

1 - when I run test command like `python manage.py test --keepdb`, the test database would be saved.

2 - But if I use the sqlite ,the test databases would default be maked in memory. It means, although I used the `--keepdb`, without setting others, the test databases would not save.

3 - If I use except sqlite, the test databases would happend in the filesystem, which means I can seem the database in a file or by the sql-control-tools.

(ps: If I had a wrong though, point it out please~)

Then, I try like this:

1 - use sqlite.

2 - make a table.

3 - write a test which save some datas to the table.

4 - try command with `--keepdb`

The result was predictable：I do not see a file or see the test database or test tables in control-tools. It may be, test databases or tables build in memory?

So, here comes the questions below:

1 - If I use the sqlite,what should I do or change settings so that I can save the test datas I can see by eyes?

Comment: But what should I do if I want it not clean the datas after testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confused  the use of argument `--keepdb` and the logic of deleteing datas after each test method!

With the argument `--keepdb`,it means would not delete the database after test.But if we had not set the `'TEST':{'name':'dbname'}` in the settings of database,it would run the test database in the memory and would not save.

The logic of deleteing datas,would clean the datas after each method named 'test_xxx_xxx()'.

So,they are different.

mybe the logic:

1 - create the test database if not exist。

2 - run the setup method to born some datas

3 - do a method that named "test_xxx_xxx"

4 - clean the datas

and then, repeat 2,3,4 until all the test methods runed

finaly - delete the test database or not.